# Output of the c program comes to be zero while it takes input from user

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, printf, scanf

I am posting the part of code that ask user to input a matrix, but while displaying it only displays 0.000000 as its elements. Please helf to find out where i am not doing proper thing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){

int i,j,m,x,c,l;
double mat[100][100],temp[100],a[100][100],lt[100][100]={0.000},ut[100][100],maximum,per[100][100];
printf("Enter the size of square matrix: ");
scanf("%d", &m);

//enter the matrix
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
printf("enter the row %d: \n", i+1);
for(j=0;j<m;j++){
scanf("%f",&mat[i][j]);
a[i][j]=mat[i][j];
}
  }

//show matrix
  printf("matrix =\n");
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
 for(j=0;j<m;j++)
 {
  printf("%f\t", mat[i][j]);
 }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Switch on compiler warnings and you will learn that you need `%lf` in `scanf` to scan a `double`. (But `%f` for _printing_  a `double` is fine, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Use **lf** to scan double values. Using wrong format specifier lead to undefined behavior

Comment: Also OP should use more descriptive names then `i or j or c`

Comment: @Rizier123 yes I agree but the reason for seeing 0 is this

Comment: Thanks. i, j, c are used as counters in program hence i have not used any descriptive name though. This is just a part of code.